# Как по клику на ссылку сменить текст в другом блоке?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

У меня есть некий фильтр с выпадающим меню. Как сделать чтобы при клике на пункт меню заменялся текст рядом с "Показать" на текст пункта меню?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.catalog-view').on('click', '.catalog-view__title', function() {
        $(this).siblings('.catalog-view__list').slideToggle(0);
    });
});
```

```css
.catalog-view {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 40px;
  display: block;
  height: 45px;
}

.catalog-view__title {
  color: #6f6f6f;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 45px;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.catalog-view__title-option {
  color: #00a651;
  padding-left: 6px;
}

.catalog-view__list {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 19px 32px 17px 14px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  width: 275px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.catalog-view__item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.catalog-view__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0a0a0a;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.catalog-view__link:hover {
  transition: .3s;
  color: #00a651;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="catalog-view"><a class="catalog-view__title" href="#">Показать <span class="catalog-view__title-option">всё</span></a>
                <ul class="catalog-view__list">
                  <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="/">Всё</a></li>
                  <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="/">Мульти пятновыводитель</a></li>
                  <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="/">Аспирекс</a></li>
                  <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="/">Универсальное моющее средство</a></li>
                  <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="/">Средство для мытья посуды</a></li>
                  <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="/">Освежитель воздуха</a></li>
                  <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="/">Спрей для кухни</a></li>
                  <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="/">Жидкий стиральный порошок</a></li>
                  <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="/">Универсальный отбеливатель</a></li>
                  <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="/">Силиконовый мульти-спрей</a></li>
                  <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="/">Ароматизированный отбеливатель</a></li>
                  <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="/">Жироудалитель</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const $catView = $('.catalog-view');
  $catView.on('click', function (e) {
    const $target = $(e.target);
    if ($target.is('.catalog-view__link'))
      $('.catalog-view__title-option').text($target.text());
    $catView.find('.catalog-view__list').slideToggle(0);
  });
});
```

```css
.catalog-view{position:relative;margin-left:40px;display:block;height:45px}.catalog-view__title{color:#6f6f6f;text-decoration:none;font-size:16px;line-height:45px;display:block;height:100%}.catalog-view__title-option{color:#00a651;padding-left:6px}.catalog-view__list{display:none;position:absolute;left:0;list-style-type:none;padding:19px 32px 17px 14px;background-color:#fff;box-shadow:0 8px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);width:275px;box-sizing:border-box}.catalog-view__item:not(:last-child){margin-bottom:15px}.catalog-view__link{text-decoration:none;color:#0a0a0a;display:block;font-size:14px}.catalog-view__link:hover{transition:.3s;color:#00a651}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="catalog-view"><a class="catalog-view__title" href="#">Показать <span class="catalog-view__title-option">всё</span></a>
  <ul class="catalog-view__list">
    <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="javascript:void(0)">Всё</a></li>
    <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="javascript:void(0)">Мульти пятновыводитель</a></li>
    <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="javascript:void(0)">Аспирекс</a></li>
    <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="javascript:void(0)">Универсальное моющее средство</a></li>
    <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="javascript:void(0)">Средство для мытья посуды</a></li>
    <li class="catalog-view__item"><a class="catalog-view__link" href="javascript:void(0)">Освежитель воздуха</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```